ActivityResultLauncher<PickVisualMediaRequest> cannot resolve method
I try use this code for pick an image:
ActivityResultLauncher<PickVisualMediaRequest> pickMedia =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(), new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
                    if (uri != null) {

                    }
                }
            });

But this signature is absent, I can see it via source code of package androidx.activity.result.
But Android Studio show as hint two other signature with additional parameters, I tried use them but fail too.
I use androidx.activity:activity:1.9.2

"But this signature is absent" -- what exactly in the code snippet is "this signature"? "But Android Studio show as hint two other signature with additional parameters" -- what exactly is Android Studio offering as alternatives? Where is your code snippet in your project (e.g., is it in a subclass of ComponentActivity)?

@CommonsWare Upps. It was not subclass of ComponentActivity. The problem is solved. Thank you very much.

registerForActivityResult() is not available in arbitrary classes. Mostly, you would use it in a subclass of ComponentActivity.

// add is this methout in the class make sure out of the any function

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
ActivityResultLauncher<PickVisualMediaRequest> pickMedia =
        registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(), uri -> {
            if (uri != null) {

            }
        });


